# Svn Authentication faliure

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnserve

I config three lines in svnserve.conf file

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

problem is when i right click on my project folder svn commit it gives Authentication faliure error

svn doesnt prompt username and password dialog [i checked in saved data in that All authentication are in cleared state]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config you should have an 'authz-db' property, that indicates the authentication database using svnserve (svn:// repositories), normally as a file with the structure:

```
[/]
user1 = rw
user2 = r
```

Then, in your passwd file you have:

```
[users]
user1 = pass1
user2 = pass2
```

However, I recommend the use of groups to aggregate different users (developers, managers).

```
[groups]
developers = user1
architects = user2

[$repo$:/]
@developers = rw
```